# Springboot: Unit testing with H2 emulating postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, unit-testing, jpa

I'm trying to test queries against H2 emulating Postgress.

The unit test look as follow:

Unit test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyRepository.class})
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:schema-test.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
//@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class ImportIdTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repo;


    @Test
    public void importIdSeqTest() {
        assertEquals(1, repo.getNexImportId());
        assertEquals(2, repo.getNexImportId());
    }
}
```

And the test application properties as follow:

application-test.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=PostgreSQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS myschema
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.datasource.platform=test
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= none
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

pom.xml

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

While running the unit test, the error I'm getting is:

`No qualifying bean of type 'cfoo.bar.MyRepository'`

while `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyRepository.class})` as been added to the unit test.

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT

As per comment, in the project code :

Repository declaration:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT nextval('import_id_seq')", nativeQuery = true)
    Long getNexImportId();
}
```

Comment: We would need to see the MyRepository class to know why the bean is not being autowired.

Comment: Your configuration is weird, you want an `@SpringBootTest` but limit the configuration to only your repository. Ditch the `@ContextConfiguration` and run your test again.

Comment: Removing it lead to the same result. Adding was an attempt to fix it

Comment: https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. Just that our pipeline don't integrate docker at the moment.